# How does the num_candidates parameter in ElasticSearch's K-nearest neighbor Search API work?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm looking for some insight into ElasticSearch's K-Nearest Neighbor Search Results api, specifically the `num_candidates` parameter.

The API excepts a request like such:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/knn-search.html

```
"knn": {
    "field": "image-vector",
    "query_vector": [-5, 9, -12],
    "k": 10,
    "num_candidates": 10000
  },
```

Is the `num_candidates` parameter value of 10,0000 saying that it is only going to search through 10,000 records? So if I have an index of 500k records would it not consider them all?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77260716/elastic-knn-search-num-candidates-vs-shard-size/77261232#77261232

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it works is [described here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/knn-search.html#tune-approximate-knn-for-speed-accuracy).

> To gather results, the kNN search API finds a num_candidates number of approximate nearest neighbor candidates on each shard. The search computes the similarity of these candidate vectors to the query vector, selecting the k most similar results from each shard. The search then merges the results from each shard to return the global top k nearest neighbors.

Basically, the top K best candidates are selected per shard and then merged together and again the top K best candidates are picked from the merge.